# Setting Content-Disposition to inline for .docx / .doc (still downloading in all browsers)

Tags: servlets, browser, download, inline, docx

I have searched it on google but didn't get proper explanation for the same
I have written the following code to open the document in the browser itself. I can't download the document for some reason so I am setting the following response headers. I am able to view the following formats in the browser:

- pdf
- xml
- text
- jpg
- png

(BUT **NOT DOC or DOCX**)

```
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("inline; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // get output stream of the response
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    outStream.flush();
    response.flushBuffer();
```

Please help me out. I wist to open the document in the browser only.

**EDIT:**

Servlet is reading MIME types perfectly even for doc and docx formats. Also MS Word is installed on my machine and .doc and .docx types mapped to Word

Comment: It is trivial but...do you have installed MS Word on your machine? Also ensure you have the .doc and .docx types mapped to Word

Comment: yes it is installed as well as mapped